# Collect data from dropdown list

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making an expense spreadsheet, to keep track of all my expenses. I have made a dropdown-list with different category (Rent, Food, Others etc.) these are put into C2 to CXX, in the next cell D2 to DXX I put the Expense number.

I would now like to have a summary cells, that tells me how much I have spent in each category (Adding all the expenses from one category together).

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a pivot table but you might use something like:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,J2,D:D)
```

copied down, where J2 is the first entry in the table driving the drop-downs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Only thing I changed is the criterion (J2 in your example) and changed it to whatever I wanted, i.e. "Food", "Rent".